# aria-role of input element with type number

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Element:

```
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="Duration"
            aria-label="duration"
          />
```

Test:

```
  const input = screen.getByRole('textbox', {
    name: /duration/i,
  });
```

When I set the input type to "text" the element is found, but when I set the type to "number", it fails. Please what is the appropriate role for an input element with type "number"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role for `input` element with type `number` is `spinbutton`.

So your code should be :

```js
const input = screen.getByRole("spinbutton", {
   name: /duration/i
});
```

Normally, when `testing-library` doesnt found the role, it shows the possible roles after test fails, something like this:

```js
Unable to find an accessible element with the role "textbox" and name `/duration/i`

Here are the accessible roles:

  spinbutton:
```

Or, if you stay in doubt you can check the possible roles for some element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#technical_summary) (e.g. **Input element -> Implicit ARIA role** item).